# Solr Document Updation

Tags: mysql, solr

I have a `wp_postmeta` table which has `post_id`, `meta_value` and `meta_key` as its columns. Then I have a `wp_customer_review` table which have all the review details of a customer for a particular post one among which is ratings.

I am indexing all these posts in Solr and using a plugin which updates the Solr index when a post gets updated. For listing the posts, upon a user query I pull the relevant documents. One such fields in the document is average ratings which means that each Solr document needs to have this field.

So at the moment I can think of two options

- Whenever the customer gives a rating for the listing I compute the average rating and update it in my `wp_postmeta`.
- Run a cron job once or twice a day to do the same job?

I am confused about the right approach. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How big are the tables? when a customer gives a rating, do you need to update 1 record? 100 records? 100,000 records? How often does the average change?

With that in mind, I'd have to assume a hybrid approach. I assume that when a listing has few records, the average can change dramatically when a review comes in. When the listing has 100,000 reviews, the average won't change over each review.

I would probably define a threshold. Under X reviews - the average would change on the spot. Over that number, the average would be calculated by the end of the day.

Answer (score 0):

Does this process need to be optimized at this point?  I mean, are your users posting reviews so fast that you're concerned about Solr resource utilization?  It sounds like one user review action will trigger at-most-one document update.

Often the quickest solution is the best initial solution.  I'd suggest just updating/reindexing the Solr doc as reviews are added:edited.

If update volume is high, start monitoring update latency and query latency to see if you see degradation under high update load.  If so, then a solution like Uri's could be in order.